# How can we save number of AudioRecorded files(.caf) with different audio data(Sounds) and different name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

Can anyone tell me how can i fetch the audio recorded data? i want to save number of recorded files with different data. what i m doing is accessing url , directory path and renaming them but as a result they are saving with different name but not with different data.all files are playing same last sound which i have been recorded.

***Source Code:-***

```
- (IBAction) startRecording
{
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
[audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&err];

if(err)
{
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}

[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
err = nil;

if(err)
{
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}

recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// We can use kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 (4:1 compression) or kAudioFormatLinearPCM for nocompression
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];

// We can use 44100, 32000, 24000, 16000 or 12000 depending on sound quality
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];

// We can use 2(if using additional h/w) or 1 (iPhone only has one microphone)
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

[recordSetting setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
[recordSetting setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSetting setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];

recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/My Sound.caf",DOCUMENTS_FOLDER];

url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];
err = nil;

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
soundData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url];
NSLog(@"soundData:%@",soundData);
NSLog(@"url:%@",url);

err = nil;
recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
if(!recorder)
{
    NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                               message: [err localizedDescription]
                              delegate: nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    return;
}

//prepare to record
[recorder setDelegate:self];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;
if (! audioHWAvailable) 
{
    UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                               message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                              delegate: nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [cantRecordAlert show];

}

// start recording
[recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 60];
Tag=30;

}


- (IBAction)saveRecording
{ 
if([recordingNameTextField.text isEqualToString: @""])
{
    [alertView setMessage:@"Recording File Name not set.\n\n"];
    [alertView show];
}
else 
{
    recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/My Sound.caf",DOCUMENTS_FOLDER];
    NSLog(@"%@",recorderFilePath);

    NSLog(@"%@",url);


    renameString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.caf",DOCUMENTS_FOLDER,recordingNameTextField.text];
    NSLog(@"%@",renameString);

    url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:renameString];
    NSLog(@"%@",url2);

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *renameError;

    [fm moveItemAtURL:url toURL:url2 error:&renameError];

    [recordingFile checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [recordingFile addRecord:1 andname:recordingNameTextField.text];
    [recordingFile readDatabase];
    recordingNameTextField.text = @"";
    NSLog(@"Text Field: %@",recordingNameTextField.text);
    saveRecording.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
}
```

Please help.Thanks :)

Comment: nikhil you should save them in database

Comment: @sandy:saving them in database.check it!!!

Comment: How many types of audio files you are using here?

Comment: @SreeCharan :single type.only recording a sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you create a database in sqlite and then create a table.below is insertion code.

```
[self databasePath];
BOOL checkQuery=NO;

const char *sqlStatement;
sqlStatement = [sql UTF8String];
    blob=voicedata; 

//if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &statement, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK) {
        checkQuery=NO;  
    }
    else {
        sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, Loc, [blob bytes], [blob length], NULL);

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement)) {
            checkQuery=NO;
        }
        else {
           // NSLog(@"Query Working nicely");
            checkQuery=YES; 

            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }
    }
//}
//sqlite3_close(database);
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

in above code,
sql= query string
blob=nsdata
loc=int value 1
try this its working fine for me if any clarification let me know....

Comment: I m not using blob file in the database.I'm just storing my varchar type of name only.

Comment: but since to store voice in database you should store in form of nsdata. because it store voice itself. if you put varchar i.e it will only store reference of your audio file. so you get last one only..

Comment: ok but can u tell me how should i use nsdata with this audiorecorder?

Comment: use below code for convert your voice in nsdata:   
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
               NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString* docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* file = [docDir stringByAppendingString:@"/recording.aif"]; voiceData  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",file]];

Comment: i have just one confusion now.i.e.NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); NSString docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; NSString* file = [docDir stringByAppendingString:@"/recording.aif"]; voiceData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",file]];  Should i use this code in startRecording or SaveRecording??

Comment: One more thing i.e.about database:-while saving blob data into database.it will save my audio data only or both name of file or audiodata??

Comment: it will save your audio file in database. to recongnize audio file you can put id for some thing else

Comment: listen what i m doing is taking two columns in a table.One has a datatype int which i have make primary key and second is blob as suggested by you.should i save name of file also??

Comment: you can save taking a varchar

Comment: OK Thanks a lot buddy.You make my day.Your help is really appreciable.Thankyou so much :)